# Authenticating users with IdentityServer4 without a Login page

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, identityserver4

We built a Xamarin.Forms app that operates as an IdentityServer4 client using the WebView implementation approach, which worked perfectly. However, Apple will not accept our app in the store because they want the authentication and new account creation to occur within the app. Therefore, I've been trying to post the credentials entered within the app's login screen to the IdentityServer with the hope that I can simulate the same process that occurs when a user enters their credentials and submits (posts) the login page:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserLoginViewModel model)
    {
        String result = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.UserName))
            {
                UserKey user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName.ToLowerInvariant());

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.SSID))
                { result = AuthenticateResultEnum.UserDoesNotExist.ToString(); }
                else
                {
                    var signin_result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, false);
                    if (signin_result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        if (_interactionService.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            LocalRedirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (signin_result.IsLockedOut)
                    { result = AuthenticateResultEnum.AccountLocked.ToString(); }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = AuthenticateResultEnum.Error.ToString();
            _logger.ExceptionAsync(ex);
        }

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

However, I've had no luck with this process because of all the redirects involved. Is there a well-established way of authenticating a user with IdentityServer without showing a login page, but instead posting the credentials and Authorization Request from the apps login form? Other well-known apps appear to be able to do so, I'm just seeking confirmation that it can be done with IdentityServer4.

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the [ResourceOwnerPassword](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html) flow. Do you 'own' the users - i.e. are both the Identity Server and app yours, or is the Identity Server from someone else?

Comment: Either use the safari view controller or the ne SFAuthenticatedSession to make Apple happy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Mashton, we do own both the app and the IdentityServer implementation. I will look into the ResourceOwnerPassword flow as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @leastprivilege, Apple did mention using the Safari View Controller, but they also stated that they prefer the authentication and new account creation be performed inside the app. I will still however look into both suggestions you mentioned in your comment. Thank you for your continued work on IdentityServer, it's very much appreciated.